# firebase facebook popup is too big

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

Whenever I try to use login with facebook provided by firebase i get this error!

[image]

even tho all other popup look just fine i can't seem to know how can i fix this one?

code :

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const config = {};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });

export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

const fbProvider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
fbProvider.setCustomParameters({ display: 'popup' });

export const signInWithFb = () => auth.signInWithPopup(fbProvider);

export default firebase;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the popup looks fine then you don't need to fix this error. It clearly states that this message is only visible to developers at the end of the warning. Does it still appear in the production build, when deployed to the registered domain?

Comment: so yea I deployed the website on netlify and it still showed, but I didn't really switch to prod in fb developers, will it go away when i do?